# Apache rewrites, Passing to an index page from just the domain or from index.shtml?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If someone types in my domain name with or without a slash I want to redirect to my php index page within my php folder.

Also I want calls to index.shtml to redirect to that page and images to again look in the root?

This is what I'm working with at the moment

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1/php/index2009.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1/php/index2009.php [L]
```

Which doesn't work

Comment: I want..., I want ..., I want... StackOverflow is for questions not requests. Try to reformulate your real question and give a bit more info about your current file structure. Now it seems that all your content in inside the php folder, so why not put everything form the php folder into the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any rewrite rules.  Just set

```
DirectoryIndex php/index2009.php
```

See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) for DirectoryIndex.